# Problem with string in to array of records in a thread

Tags: arrays, string, thread-safety, record

need help with some weird record/array-problem, tried everything i could think of, but to no avail.

I start a thread from the main thread, which checks the online state of some network devices
every 30 seconds and writes the results into an array of records as declared below.

```
Type TPingRec = Record
     PingDevice: String; //name of networkpanel (DEV0 -> DEVx)
     Pingtarget: String; //something like "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/status?"
     DevState: String; //contains the resturnstring from Http.Get
     DoPing: Boolean; //determines if this device should be pinged or not
     PingResult: Boolean; //device online or not
                end;
type
  TpingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    pingHTTP: TidHTTP;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure updateOnlineStatus;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;


main-form, variables ...

Var PingRec: Array of TPingRec;
```

In the main thread i initialize the array before starting the thread.

```
procedure TfMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
.....
 loadnetworkDevices; 
 PingThread:=TpingThread.Create;
.....
end;

procedure TfMain.loadnetworkDevices;
Var 
    n: Integer;
    aDev: TNetDevice;
    ....
begin
setlength(PingRec,1);
for n:=0 to 255 do begin
    aDev:=FC('DEV'+inttostr(n)) AS TNetDevice;
    if (aDev<>NIL) then begin
       ....
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].PingDevice:=aDev.Name; 
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].Pingtarget:=aDev.Http_Status; 
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].PingResult:=False;
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].DoPing:=True; 
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].DoPing:=aDev.OnlineTest; 
       PingRec[High(PingRec)].DevState:='K';
       SetLength(PingRec,Length(PingRec)+1);
                        end Else Break;
                   end;
SetLength(PingRec,Length(PingRec)-1); 
....
end;
```

The thread takes the value "PingTarget" which holds mainly the ip-daddress of the device to be "pinged"
and runs a idHTTP.Get against each device.
If the device is online, back comes a very long string and i set another variable of the record from false to true, otherwise an exception is raised and the variable is set to false.

```
procedure TPingThread.Execute;
Var response: String;
    n: Byte;
begin
pingHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
pingHTTP.ConnectTimeout:=3000;
pingHTTP.ReadTimeout:=3000;
while NOT Terminated do begin
      for n:=0 to High(PingRec) do begin
          if (PingRec[n].DoPing) then begin //ping the device
             try
               pingHTTP.Response.Clear;
               response:=StringReplace(pingHTTP.Get(PingRec[n].Pingtarget),#$D#$A,'',[rfReplaceAll]);
               if (response='') Then begin 
                  PingRec[n].PingResult:=False; 
                  PingRec[n].DevState:=''; 
                  pingHTTP.Disconnect; 
                                     end
                                Else begin 
                  //at this point DevState really has the value of "response"
                  PingRec[n].DevState:=response; 
                  //as soon as this field is (re)set, the value of DevState disappears
                  //and DevState becomes empty string
                  PingRec[n].PingResult:=True; 
                                     end;
             except 
               PingRec[n].PingResult:=False;
               PingRec[n].DevState:=''; 
               pingHTTP.Disconnect; 
             end;
                                    end 
                               Else begin //do not ping the device 
             PingRec[n].PingResult:=True; 
             PingRec[n].DevState:=''; 
                             end;
                                   end; //For n
      Synchronize(updateonlineStatus);
      //WaitforSingleObject ....as delay
      If (Terminated) Then Break; end;
                        end;
pingHTTP.Free;
end;
```

As you can see by the code, the thread synchronizes with the main thread, setting the state of several Panels
(referring to the physical network-devices) to "stOnline" or "stOffline".
In addition, the http.get-returnstring is written into another variable of the record, because it includes information
that i want to use somewhere else in the program.

So far all of this works fine!

My problem is in the field "DevState".
When this field gets assigned the value of "response", the value first equals "reasponse".
But as soon as in the next line i assign a value to the field "PingResult" the value in the field "DevState" is replaced by an empty string while PingResult gets the correct new value!

The arrays values are modified/initialized only once in the main thread, afterwards it only gets modified
in the "pingthread"-loop, the main thread just reads the values during program-cycle.

I tried to initialize "DevState" with a "K", but same result.

Previously i assigned the http.Get-result directly to the record-field,
i implemented the "response"-variable just for stepping.

Removing #§D#$A from the http.Get has no influence on the behaviour.